# Error en el setOnClickListener de un botón

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

### Error al dar funcionalidad a un botón en un activity

> Al dar la funcionalidad de onClick me da un error lo que hace que la app no se ejecute.

class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

```
//private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
//val db = Firebase.firestore

var etEmailLogin: EditText?=null
var etPasswordLogin: EditText?=null
var btnContinuar: Button?=null

val TAG="LoginActivity"

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    etEmailLogin=this.findViewById(R.id.etEmailLogin)
    etPasswordLogin=this.findViewById(R.id.etPasswordLogin)
    btnContinuar=this.findViewById(R.id.btnContinuar)

    btnContinuar!!.setOnClickListener(this)

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
    btnRegLogin.setOnClickListener {
        startActivity(Intent(this,RegisterActivity::class.java))
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_from_right,R.anim.slide_to_left)
    }

}

override fun onClick(v: View?) {

    if (v == btnContinuar){
        Log.v(TAG, "btnContinuar pulsado")
    }
}

/*fun descargarUsuarioConectado(){
    db.collection("/users").document(auth.currentUser!!.uid).get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
            if (document != null && document.data != null) {
                DataHolder.profileUser=document.toObject(users::class.java)!!
                val intent: Intent = Intent(requireContext(), MainActivity::class.java)
                requireActivity().startActivity(intent)
                requireActivity().finish()
            }else{
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            Log.d(TAG,"get failed with ", exception)
        }
}*/
```

}

> En el logcat el btnContinuar!!.setOnClickListener(this) hace que se produzca un error, y aparece lo siguiente en el logcat:

```
2021-03-03 19:49:44.860 4750-4750/com.example.hobbietest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.hobbietest, PID: 4750
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hobbietest/com.example.hobbietest.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.hobbietest.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.kt:30)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

> He comentado el setOnClickListener y la app funciona bien, pero claro, no tengo la funcionalidad que quiero de ese botón. Adjunto una foto para que se aprecie mejor:
> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findViewById()` retorna `null` si lo llamas antes de `setContentView()`. Eso es lo que mas tarde causa la `NullPointerException`.Todo lo que debes hacer es cambiar el orden:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
    etEmailLogin=this.findViewById(R.id.etEmailLogin)
    etPasswordLogin=this.findViewById(R.id.etPasswordLogin)
    btnContinuar=this.findViewById(R.id.btnContinuar)
    btnContinuar?.setOnClickListener(this)
    btnRegLogin.setOnClickListener {
        startActivity(Intent(this,RegisterActivity::class.java))
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_from_right,R.anim.slide_to_left)
    }
}
```

Comment: En ese caso debes aceptar la respuesta. Hay un botón para eso debajo del contador de puntos

Answer (score 0):

Puedes declarar lo que quieras hacer dentro de una función y declarar el setOnClickListener en el onCreate

```
btnContinuar!!.setOnClickListener{
    btnAction() 
}
```

luego la función fuera del onCreate

```
private fun btnAction(){
    //acción del boton
}
```

Creo que el error puede ser porque en el método onClick estas pasando una vista y la estas comparando con un botón, eso podría provocar el NullPointerException.

Comment: Pero la funcion onViewCreated es en fragmentos, y en este caso es un Activity

Comment: Entonces puedes ponerlo en tu onCreate

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar